# How to get the length one column in all tables in one database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble to get the max length of records in one column in all tables.

I would only like to display the max length for each table for the specific column.

Below is what I have tried, I already found the way to return the column I need, but now, i need to get the max len. I know this is not the right way.

```
select  max(len(site)) as site from 
(
SELECT  t.name AS TableName 
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'site%')A
```

The expected result will display the column name, the table name and also the max length of the records for that column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about column names, or table contents?

Comment: column name and table contents(data) sir. thanks

Comment: did you have a look here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482897/list-all-sql-columns-with-max-length-and-greatest-length

Comment: I did, but it seems like i need to hard code my table name, i have more than 50 tables to check, so i tried using this way. will it be possible?

Comment: sys.columns and sys.tables can give you the longest column names. To find the longest table contents, you'll have to search each table. This seems to be a problem caused by a poor design. Start over from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what are you really trying to do, but I think you want something like

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  Site1 VARCHAR(45)
);
CREATE TABLE T2(
  Site2 VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('A'), ('AA');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('BBB'), ('BBBBB');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
              N'(SELECT MAX(LEN(' + --You can also add ISNULL([Col],0) to get 0
              QUOTENAME(c.name) + ')) FROM '+ 
              QUOTENAME(t.name) + ') AS ' + 
              QUOTENAME(t.name + '.'+c.name) + ', '
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'site%';

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL)-1);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Which will returns:

```
+----------+----------+
| T1.Site1 | T2.Site2 |
+----------+----------+
|        2 |        5 |
+----------+----------+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=71439b99cd3bf4b095b73d98c4993dac)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:You will get individual Scripts to execute.

```
select 'select Max(len('+COLUMN_NAME+')),'''+COLUMN_NAME+ ''' as ColumnName ,'''+TABLE_NAME+''' as TableName from ' +table_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'YourColumnName'
```

Comment: sorry i dont really get you

Comment: @MichaelJ The above code will get you the scripts which u have to execute in a loop to get the details of the Length of Column , Column Name and Table Name. Replace 'YourColumnName' with what ever column you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you may try to generate a dynamic SQL statement and execute this statement:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N''

-- Dynamic SQL
SELECT @stm = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
        N'UNION ALL ',
        N'SELECT ''',
        t.name,
        N''' AS TableName, ''',
        c.name,
        N''' AS ColumnName, ',
        N'ValueLength = (SELECT MAX(LEN(',
        QUOTENAME(c.name),
        ')) FROM ',
        QUOTENAME(t.name),
        N')'
   )
   FROM sys.columns c
   JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
   WHERE c.name LIKE 'site%'
   ORDER BY t.name, c.name
   FOR XML PATH('')
)
SET @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, N'')

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```